# HTML5 Componenet inheritance with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, inheritance, directive

I am writing a mobile web-app with AngularJS and have similar components in different views (see image here: [Similar Component in different views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR3rN.png))

I have created a directive for one of the components. Now I would like to rewrite most of the code since they are basically the same (so I wouldn't have to maintain the same code twice). Sharing functionality via services, etc. is not really the problem here, but the different 'HTML content'.

What is the best way to reuse my existing directive? Can I maybe "inject" a directive into the primary directive when calling it or something similar?

Here is a code example of what I am looking for:

```
app.directive('directiveOne', function() {
return {
    template: '<table><tr>
                   <td class="image"><img ...></img></td>
                   <td class="generic-input"></td>
                   <td class="dynamic-input">
                        <p>I am something</p>
                   </td>
               </tr></table>'
};


app.directive('directiveTwo', function() {
return {
    template: '<table><tr>
                   <td class="image"><i class="icon-one"></i></td>
                   <td class="generic-input"></td>
                   <td class="dynamic-input">
                        <p>I am something</p>
                        <p>I am something else</p>
                        <form>And I also have a form</form>
                   </td>
               </tr></table>'
};
```

I have the two very similar templates as directives., i.e. in the above attached picture I would call a version of the master-directive to show the left image and a second version of it for the right picture instead of writing two nearly identical directives?

Comment: If you can make your directives so that one is an outer and one is an inner directive, you can `restrict: 'A',` the inner one. And then you can set it as an HTML attribute to others.

Comment: But how would I position my code in the above directive through that?
e.g: <outer-dir inner-dir></outer-dir>

The directive would be "inside" but how would I put into a table-cell oder into a specific div, etc.

Comment: by using transclusion ;)

Comment: Really not clear what the specific problem is. Directives are extremely flexible. Provide example to illustrate issue

Comment: @charlietfl I added a small example of what I mean. Basically I wrote an html template for the left side of the attached picture and want to reuse this template (without having the same code twice) for the right side of the (attached) picture

Comment: So break down what the differences would be. For example `template` can be a function that returns  string and that function has access to the attributes on main element. Slight variations in that string can then be returned. Or template can use things like `ng-if` or `ng-class`

Comment: @charlietfl I am already using ng-if to hide content based on passed parameters, but the directive is starting to look clunky because now I basically define four different versions of this directive and have all the code in one giant template. Therefore I was wondering whether there is a more elegant way (as inheritance in Java classes for example)

Comment: Can even return a different  `templateUrl` based on attributes using function. Or nested directives . Or pass in config object to isolated scope. Very hard to help without more specifics. Again...directives are very flexible